# Writing XML using PHP have no effects after script is runned

Tags: php, xml

I am encountering problems writing XML files using PHP. The following is my php script to write content into an xml file. Basically, no errors have been encountered; but when I check my xml file after running the script, it is empty. Please advice. Thank you.

```
        $doc= new DOMDocument();
        $doc->load("articles.xml");
        $b = $doc->createElement( "articleDraft" );

          $id = $doc->createElement("id"); 
            $id->appendChild( 
            $doc->createTextNode( $_POST['id'] ) ); 
            $b->appendChild( $id ); 
          $draft=$doc->createElement("draftContent");
          $draft->appendChild($doc->createTextNode($_POST['articleBody']));
          $b->appendChild($draft);
          $time=$doc->createElement("drafTime");
          $draft->appendChild($doc->createTextNode(time()));
          $b->appendChild($time);

        $doc->save("articles.xml");
```

I am new to writing xml in PHP, please help me identify other problems if you find any. Thank you.

Comment: This needs some basic debugging first. Have you tried to create just one element and save the file and see if it works? So would be helpful if you could reduce your question's code to just the first part that does not work.

Comment: What does $doc->save("articles.xml"); return?? If its a number > 0 then its worked, if FALSE is returned an error occurred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply forgot:

```
$doc->appendChild($b);
```

Edit: If you want to format your output, add:

```
$doc->formatOutput = true;
```

Otherwise your output is not human-friendly.

Comment: No problem. If my answer helped you, simply mark it as solution.

Answer (score 2):

$doc->appendChild($b); before save

Comment: Perhaps he simply started writing before the answer you wrote got loaded into his page.

Comment: I don't think he needed about 9 minutes for writing 3-4 words and getting refreshed by ajax.

Comment: Sorry about the duplicated answer.